# Need to access .digitalocean_password

Tags: mysql, configuration, cloud

After setting up Digital Ocean droplet, it says my MySQL password is stored in .digitalocean_password

Is this a folder, some kind of file? How do I access it?

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer: use command

```
cat /root/.digitalocean_password
```